# docker nginx container https refuses to working

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, angular7

we have a website we need to be https only.
it works perfectly fine if we take out the code to run https.

It is an angular 7 app running on nginx in docker. Its going to be hosted in azure.

Docker file:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as 'builder'
FROM node:8-alpine as builder

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

 ## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist 
 folder
 RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer


 ### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
COPY /certs /etc/nginx/
## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From 'builder' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default 
nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The default.conf file:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

and finally our nginx.conf file:

```
# nginx Configuration File
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;

worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name digitise.co.za www.digitise.co.za;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
       }

       # force https-redirects
       if ($scheme = http) {
           return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
       }
   }
}
```

We are running in a windows enviroment. We are still new to nginx as we used to always use iis, but with the move to azure we need to use nginx.

we build the image by running
     `docker build -t digitise .`
we then run the image by running
     `docker run -p 3000:80 -p 3001:443 digitise`

on my dev machine hitting http://localhost:3001 does redirect me to https://localhost.
hitting https://localhost:3001 has no effect. it doesn't even hit the server.
hitting http://localhost:3000 returns Bad request, the plain http request was sent to https port

Comment: Shouldn't you specify port number in `proxy_pass` directive? Else which port would it proxy to?

Comment: tried that but doesn't work. i get the cert not valid warning and if i click continue it doesn't work

Comment: Sure you will get the error if your use `localhost` to access your service. There’re not too many options if you want to use the same certificate - edit `hosts` file on your machine to point your domain from certificate to `localhost`. Alternatively you could use a different, self-signed certificate for local testing. I actually think it might be better than including private key into docker image.